# Transfer a string from list view on one activity to another in android

Tags: android, string, listview

How is it possible to transfer a string from a listView on click and use the string saved in a variable in a different activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by writing code for calling next activity in listview's item click event

```
Intent intent= new Intent(getBaseContext(),AnotherActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ANY_KEY", "YOUR STRING VALUE");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Then in other activity's on create method get value of your string by

```
String str=getIntent().getStringExtra("ANY_KEY");
```

Comment: when you get the intent would you have to keep it as  "ANY_KEY" or will using ANY_KEY work?

Comment: No it will not worked you must have to use "ANY_KEY" , i have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use a code like this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity2.class);
                    i.putExtra("var", (String)lv.getAdapter().getItem(position));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
```

And in the Activity2 get the var

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String var = bundle.getString("var");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(fisrtActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(name of extra,String);
startActivity(intent);
```

To get in secondActivity:

```
Intent i = getIntent()
String s = i.getStringExtra(name of extra);
```

Comment: would the name of extra need speech marks around them or not e.g "name_of_extra" or name_of_extra

Comment: "name_of_extra", but you can choose your name instead name_of_extra

Answer (score 0):

modify your adapter class as follows and try ,

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
            long arg3) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context/getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("value", your_list.get(position));
        context/getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
```

in order to get the value ,

```
String yourString  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("value");
```

Comment: How would you go about getting the string from the listview?

Comment: where do you store the strings ?

Comment: I'm assuming when you pass this on to the second activity you need to do something list this: `Intent intent = getIntent();
 valueId = intent.getStringExtra("value");`

Comment: of course you need, how else you can get the transferred data ?

Comment: Basically what i'm doing is downloading a list of user from a database. Convert it to string and displaying it on a list view. Up to that bit is fine. When i click on a specific user to covert it to string and attempt to use it in another activity I keep getting the message that the variable is null.

Comment: Obviously I understand you have to do that @David I was just wondering if the formatting was okay.

Comment: as you said you got a list ,  you have to put it into intent.putExtra() and get value from getExtra()

Comment: i have edit the anwser and "value" is not a keyword, you can put any string you need